# почему неработает "Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;"

Tags: c#, unity3d

использую Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; для вращения игрока, но курсор не возвращается в центр, незнаю что с этим делать, вот код (использую Photon для Мультиплеера)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PhotonView view;
    public Vector2 cur;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        if(view.IsMine)
        {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.back * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            
            cur = Input.mousePosition;
            this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(this.transform.rotation.x +(-Input.mousePosition.y / 30), this.transform.rotation.x + (Input.mousePosition.x /30), 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть проблема в том что вы делаете это каждый раз в `Update`.

Вот код:

```cs
...

void Start()
{
    ...

    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

...
```

И ещё уберите строку `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;` из `Update`.